# click word to change image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to find a simple javascript script to be able to click on a word to change the background image of my page.

This is what I have, but it is not working and I am not sure why, when I read the console it says the following:

> `[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElementbyId('pic')') global code`

```js
var pic = document.getElementbyId('pic');
var word = document.getElementbyId('clickme');

word.onclick = function() {
  pic.src = "http://www.evolutionsupply.com/_images/image9.gif"
}
```

```html
<image id="pic" width="1000" height "400" src="http://www.oldyelladogranch.com/puppies.jpg" />
</image>
<div id="clickme"><u>clickme</u>
</div>
```

I just just random pictures of dogs as a stand-in

Comment: Why are you closing your opening `<image />` tag and then adding a `</image>` afterwards? ...

Comment: `getElementbyId` should be `getElementById`. JavaScript is case sensetive.

Comment: This should be closed: "off topic because... -> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."

Answer (score 3):

You error was in `getElementbyId` the correct is `getElementById` ( CAPITAL `B`)
Try this instead:

```
<image id="pic" width="1000" height"400" src="http://www.oldyelladogranch.com/puppies.jpg" /> 
</image>
<div id="clickme"><u>clickme</u></div>

<script>
var pic = document.getElementById('pic');
var word =document.getElementById('clickme');

word.onclick = function(){
pic.src = "http://www.evolutionsupply.com/_images/image9.gif"
}
</script>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/VLZQOV)

Answer (score 1):

It's not `getElementbyId`, it's `getElementById`